# How to create a link using BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a HTML page that has a table with rows of information (test cases, failed, warning, total # of tests)
I want each row in the Test Cases column to be a link to another page.
As you see in the image below, **my goal is for Test 1 to be a link**.
 [image]
Below is the code that I wrote to build what you see in the image.
Thanks.

```
import bs4
f = open("practice.html", 'w')
html = """<html>
                      <body>
                          <table class="details" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" style="width:95%">
                          </table>
                      </body>
                  </html>"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
table = soup.find('table')
tr = bs4.Tag(table, name='tr')
HTMLColumns = ["Test Cases", "Failed", "Warning", "Total number of tests"]
for title in HTMLColumns:  # Add titles to each column
        td = bs4.Tag(tr, name='td')
        td.insert(0, title)
        td.attrs['style'] = 'background-color: #D6FCE9; font-weight: bold;'
        tr.append(td)
table.append(tr)
results = ["Test 1", str(5), str(3), str(6)]
tr = bs4.Tag(table, name='tr')
for index, r in enumerate(results):  # loop through whole list of issue tuples, and create rows
        td = bs4.Tag(tr, name='td')
        td.attrs['style'] = 'background-color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;'
        td.string = str(r)
        tr.append(td)
table.append(tr)

f.write(soup.prettify())
f.close()
```

Below is code for creating a link that I took from BeautifulSoup documentation:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("<b></b>", "lxml")
original_tag = soup.b

new_tag = soup.new_tag("a", href="http://www.example.com")
original_tag.append(new_tag)
original_tag
# <b><a href="http://www.example.com"></a></b>

new_tag.string = "Link text."
original_tag
# <b><a href="http://www.example.com">Link text.</a></b>
f = open("practice.html", 'w')
f.write(soup.prettify())
f.close()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @PedroLobito
Following code creates a link. My issue is how to put it into the table I create above.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("<b></b>", "lxml")
original_tag = soup.b

new_tag = soup.new_tag("a", href="http://www.example.com")
original_tag.append(new_tag)
original_tag
# <b><a href="http://www.example.com"></a></b>

new_tag.string = "Link text."
original_tag
# <b><a href="http://www.example.com">Link text.</a></b>
f = open("practice.html", 'w')
f.write(soup.prettify())
f.close()

Comment: Please update your question and add an example of the current and desired outputs.

Comment: I updated and boldfaced what my desired output is. My current output is what you see in the image.

Comment: We need code,not images.

Comment: The code is already there.

Comment: The output code my friend...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# This is updated code 
# You just need to add: a = bs4.Tag(td, name='a') to you'r code 
# Then you need to fill it:

    #     if index == 0: 
    #         a.attrs[''] = 'a href="http://www.yahoo.com"'
    #     a.string = r  
    #     td.append(a)



import bs4
f = open("practice.html", 'w')
html = """<html>
                      <body>
                          <table class="details" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" style="width:95%">
                          </table>
                      </body>
                  </html>"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
table = soup.find('table')
tr = bs4.Tag(table, name='tr')
HTMLColumns = ["Test Cases", "Failed", "Warning", "Total number of tests"]
for title in HTMLColumns:  # Add titles to each column
    td = bs4.Tag(tr, name='td')
    td.insert(0, title)
    td.attrs['style'] = 'background-color: #D6FCE9; font-weight: bold;'
    tr.append(td)
table.append(tr)
results = [str(k), str(v), str(0), str(v)]
tr = bs4.Tag(table, name='tr')
for index, r in enumerate(results):  # loop through whole list of issue tuples, and create rows
    td = bs4.Tag(tr, name='td')
    td.attrs['style'] = 'background-color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;'
    a = bs4.Tag(td, name='a') 
    if index == 0:
        a.attrs[''] = 'a href="http://www.yahoo.com"'
    a.string = r
    td.append(a)
    tr.append(td)
table.append(tr)  # append the row to the table 
f.write(soup.prettify())
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

**How-to create a link using BeautifulSoup with label, attrs and target**

```
import bs4

def a_href(url, label='', target='_blank', **kwargs):
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('')
    combined_attrs = dict(target=target, href=url, **kwargs)
    tag = soup.new_tag(name='a', attrs=combined_attrs)
    tag.string = label
    return str(tag)  # or tag.prettify() for better formatting
```

**Tests**

```
class TestAHref(TestCase):

    def test_simple_link(self):
        self.assertEqual('<a href="www.ya.com" target="_blank"></a>', a_href('www.ya.com'))

    def test_link_with_attrs(self):
        self.assertEqual('<a href="ya.com" target="_self" x="1" y="2">XYZ</a>',
                         a_href('ya.com', x=1, y=2, target='_self', label='XYZ'))
```

Comment: could you add some human explanations of your solution? that would be great

Comment: @snoobdogg see the test cases!